# How to restore Arabic text of very old emails

Tags: email, character-encoding, arabic

I have an old Yahoo mail account, and I have very old emails since 2006 written in Arabic, but the encoding of these emails looks very weird, something like:

```
Óæì Ø *Ý æÚæÏß ßáÇã Ý * ßáÇã. ÇÍÈß ÊÕæÑ ÈÑÛã ÇáÍæÇÌÒ ÈÑÛã ÇáÇãÇä * ÇáæÓÇÚ ÇáÚæÇÌÒ. ÇÑ *Ïß ÊÕæÑ æÇÝÊÍ äæÇÝÐ *Ì * ÇáÝÌÑ ÈÇßÑ ãäæÑ æäÇÌÒ
```

I believe these emails were written probably in Windows-1256 encoding. I don't know how to restore them in correct Arabic encoding.

I have tried to paste the text in `Kate` and save the document in cp 1256 encoding, but it does not work.

Comment: Try replying to that email with a CC to your gmail account and try to view it there. You might also try forwarding as attachment to gmail and then viewing it there. Also try viewing on Email Clients like Outlook and ThunderBird. [[[[ Copy Paste will not work, because you are Pasting the **Decoded** text ; You have to use the raw **UnDecoded** bytes to **Decode** Properly ]]]]

Comment: @Prem Unfortunately, I tried the CC reply that you have regarded but it does not work too.

Comment: You should try "forward as attachment" & view on gmail or Outlook.

Comment: I could not finf "Forward as attachment" on Yahoo, but next to the forward button, there is a menu button with option "View raw message" it worked fine and I could able to read the correct text.

Answer (score 1):

The "**View raw message**" option is the solution to read the message in plain text. It could be accessed from the "more" button next to the forward button in Yahoo mail. However, be sure to allow popup in your browser, because it opened in a popup.

---

[image]